# How can one prove that a real function is closed?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am defining a closed function to be one that takes closed sets to closed sets. Given a function, domain and codomain, you could prove that it is not closed by simply providing a counter example according to what has been provided.

But in light of that, how would one actually prove that a given function **is** closed?

Comment: Do you mean closed intervals or closed sets? Because then the constant function is not closed by this definition.

Comment: Thank you. I had confused the two concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same "problem" with continuity: a counterexample to show non-continuity is easy (e.g. an open set whose inverse image is not open), but to show continuity you need to show *every* open set has an open inverse image.

Here you just have to show every closed set has a closed image. Sometimes you get this "for free", if $f$ is already known to be continuous and the domain is compact and the co-domain is Hausdorff, as a classic example of this. Or it's trivial, in the case of a map with finite image onto a $T_1$ space. I believe polynomials on the reals are closed functions, so this gives you a class of examples as well.

Y could also apply to other theorems: e.g. the projection $p: X \times Y \rightarrow X, p(x,y)= x$ is closed when $Y$ is compact, or a covering map with finite fibres is closed etc.

It is true that closed maps have fewer preservation properties: with continuity you have that products (both algebraic as Cartesian), restrictions, sums, quotients etc. of continuous maps are continuous. With closed maps you don't have that many that I'm aware of. Of course the restriction of a closed map to a closed set will be closed again.